# Upgrade Apache to latest version in ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am pretty new to Unix/Apache/PHP platform/tech.

I need to update the apache server from 2.4.7 to latest version 2.4.54

I am about the follow the steps from this post https://haneefputtur.com/upgrade-apache-to-latest-version-in-ubuntu-server-20.html

My current Ubuntu version is - 14.04.6

My current PHP version is - 7.0.18

I am not able to find the apache compatibility matrix with ubuntu and php.
Can you please advise apache 2.4.54 is compatible with Ubuntu 14.0.46 and PHP 7.0.8?

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 7.0.x is beyond end of life and no longer gets security fixes. 7.0.18 isn't even the most recent point release so you have known security problems.

Comment: Running it in a docker container is maybe an option. If you have the option, isn't it better to update your server now to 22.04? Ubuntu 14.04.6 end of live is in April 2024.